# How do I uninstall VS Packages without Packages Cache folder?

Tags: c#, windows, entity-framework, visual-studio, installation

I've been trying to uninstall a previous package of Entity Framework package in VisualStudio 2013, but I keep getting an error showing that it cant't find EFTools.msi in Packages Cache folder. I must say that I've deleted that folder and I don't know how to get the msi file again. Any ideas on how I could uninstall that version to install a newer one?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install "Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio 2012 & 2013" again and you should get back missing file. Then before uninstalling just copy folder somewhere.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=40762